# Linking third table with other two table to have a dynamic populated data inside using postgresql

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema, postgresql-9.2

I am in a phase where I need to have a data populated dynamically in a table which is associated with two other tables using foreign key constraint. Below is the schema/table that I have created in PostgreSQL.

Table#1:

```
application
--------------------------
id | name | size | rate
```

Table# 1 "application" have 'id' as "serial" which is also a primary key and 'name' as Varchar, 'Size' and 'rate' as Integer

Table#2:

```
Create
-------------------------
createId | name | score
```

Similarly. createId is again a serial and a primary key of this table and 'name' as varchar and 'score' as integer.

Now, I am creating a third table which is suppose to be a mapping table of the above two with a following fields-

Table# 3

```
app_create
---------------------
app_create_id | id | createId |
```

In the above table, I have made app_create_id again a sequence and a primary key and other two fields as a foreign key with references to above tables application(Id) and create(createId).

Next, when I am inserting values inside table # 1 and # 2, my understanding says that it should automatically populate it into third table#3 with respect to the data I inserted in other two tables. But, instead I am getting a blank table meaning having no values in table # 3 (app_create) the mapping table. (after insertion in table # 1 & 2)

I am looking to have the output something like this shown below, like for example-
application table and create table have following data populated-

```
application
--------------------------
id | name | size | rate    
1  |    xyz  |   2096 | 12                                         
2  |   mno   |  1280  | 34


Create
-------------------------
createId | name | score                                                         
1        | a.b.c | 50       
2       |  m.cpm  |20
```

Now, after I inserted data into these two above table, I am not sure what will happen in my third below table. I thought it will also get populated the same way as soon as I am populating the above two table as there is a primary and foreign key relationship.

Table# 3

```
app_create
----------------------------------
app_create_id | id | createId |
```

I believe it has something to do with many-to-many relationship, but I am not sure how should I make the one or any right way how to proceed the same and have the output likewise. 
Please help me understand and correct me if I am doing anything wrong or guide me how should I proceed in order to have the data inside a mapping table# 3 dynamically?

Comment: Nothing will happen until you explicitly insert data yourself into your third table. Referential integrity is for checking whether a parent row exists when you insert it into a child table, not for inserting data for you.

Comment: @peterm: thank you for your response. Could you please suggest me any way how can I do the mapping in order to have data inserted inside my third table.

Comment: Seems to be basically the same question as the one you posted on dba.SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/45437/7788 . Please don't post across the sites like that, and *expecially* not without linking between them, it wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Sorry about that I am new to StackOverflow. I will keep that in mind. Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

This does have to do with many-to-many relationship. The reason why it's impossible for anyone  to fill in table 3 for you is because no one knows what the relationship is. Thus, you need to fill it in yourself. How are applications related to creates? (What are creates?)

So the question you need to ask yourself/boss/coworkers is: Which applications should be connected to which creates?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how foreign keys are used. They tell the DBMS that a subrow of values for a column list must also appear as a subrow of values for another column list. They can be associated with effects on a table update cascading to referenced table updates.

Normally we would expect a base table with foreign key references, like any base table, to be updated by the user according to the rule/predicate/criterion for putting rows into or keeping them out of the table.

What you are describing is close to a *view*. Ie a virtual table whose value is the current value of an expression involving bases or other views. You have to say what expression you want. (It is not based on foreign keys.) But after that the DBMS calculates the appropriate value.

Here here you may be expecting that `app_create` (ignoring `app_create_id`) is the join of the other two:

```
create view app_create as
select id, createId
from application JOIN create
```

(But you don't explain what the output should look like or give example output.)

This doesn't account for `app_create_id`. However by virtue of the join, `(id, createId)` is unique. (In some SQL DBMSs that can be declared.) So you don't need `app_create_id`.

But a`pp_create_id` is problematic anyway. How should its value be determined? It would have to be a function of id and create and maybe something else. Can the same value identify different rows at different times? Can two different `(id, createId)` pairs use the same `app_create_id` at different times?